# Why does a temp table work but not a permanent table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

I've written a SQL query for a report that creates a permanent table and then performs a bunch of inserts and updates to get all the data, according to company policy. It runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio and in Crystal Reports 2008 on my machine. However, when I schedule it to run on the server with SAP BusinessObjects Central Management Console, it fails with the error "Associated statement not prepared." 
I have found that changing this permanent table to be a temp table makes the query work. Why would this be?

Comment: Does this have something to do with concurrent users accessing the same report?

Comment: @SliverNinja, I thought it might, but it was still failing even after we ruled that out.

Comment: I've always used temporary tables for running reports to avoid locking issues - permanent tables for reporting can get you into trouble, I realize this doesn't help you, but your new solution is actually better. This applies to both SQL Reporting and Crystal Reporting experiences.

Comment: We always put SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED at the top of the query to deal with locking issues (that's what I was told anyway, I don't actually know what that statement does). What's strange is that we've done dozens of reports with permanent tables, and this is the only time there's been a problem.

Comment: @Diana134 That is horrible to use in all but a very few cases and when you do use it you better really really understand the dangers.  The only time I will ever use that is to run a count on a table ad-hoc as I'm importing a huge set of data in a single transaction.  Read any book or search on google and all the SQL Server Guru's will show many reasons not to use it.

Comment: *‘when I schedule it to run on the server’* – How often is it supposed to run? Could it happen that a new instance was started while the previous one was still running? That would explain why the permanent table way couldn't work but the temp one could.

Answer (score 1):

Some research shows that this error is sometimes sent instead of the true error.  Other people reporting it talk of foreign key and (I would also assume) duplicate key errors.

Things I would check:

- Does your permanent table have any unique constraints that might be violated?  Or any foreign key constraints?
- Are you creating indexes on the table after it has been created?
- Are you creating any views over this permanent table?
- What happens if the table already exists before the job is run?
- What happens to the table if the job fails?
- Are there any intermediate steps (such as within a stored procedure) that might involve additional temp or permanent tables?

ETA:  Also check what schema the permanent table belongs to:  is it usually created with "dbo"?  Are you specifying that explicitly?  Is there any chance that there might be a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is often a generic error. Are you able to run it on the server as the account that it is scheduled to run as? It is most likely a permission error or constraint issue.

Comment: There is only the one account on the server. It fails to run for anyone that tries to schedule it unless it uses a temp table.

Comment: @Diana134 When you say 'my machine', I assume even SQL is your SQL instance. Is that correct? Basically, have you tried to run this directly on the server and see if you get any errors?

Comment: As far as I know, I personally do not have access to the server except through the management console. I'm presuming our more experienced reporting analyst has tried that, though I don't know for sure. In any case, the temp table method was the only way she could make it work too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really need a regular table, why it's not possible to create the permanent table once, vs creating it every time you run the query? 
Recreating regular user table each time query runs does not seem right. But to make it work you may try to recreate the table in a separate batch or query (e.g. put GO in the script, that splits it into separate queries).

Regarding why it happens, I'm thinking about statement caching. Server compiles the query and stores the result for some time in case same query has to run again. So it's my speculation that it tries to run the compiled query which refers to the table you have already dropped and recreated under the same name. Name is the same, but physically it's a new table. You could hit some bug in the server this way. Just a speculation, it can be different kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code it's a guess, but being that you are creating a permanent table *everytime* you run the report, I assume you must be dropping the table at some point? (Or you'd have a LOT of tables building up over time.)

I suggest a couple angles to consider:

1) Make certain to prefix tables (perhaps by a session ID or soemthing) if you are concerned about concurrency/locking issues and the like so each report run has a table exclusive to itself.

2) If you are dropping the table at the end, instead adjust your logic to leave the table be. Write code that drops when you (re)start the operation. It's possible the report is clinging to the table and you are destroying it prematurely.